# GET requests succeeds in browser, fails using Python requests library

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to grab [this JSON file](http://www.canistream.it/services/search?movieName=The%20Wizard%20of%20Oz) (actually a series of similar files, but I digress) using the requests library in Python. The file is readily accessible by browser, and I was able to download it using curl without any problem. But when I attempt to use requests to download it, I get a 403 error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://www.canistream.it/services/search?movieName=The%20Wizard%20of%20Oz")
>>> r.content
'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/0.7.62</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

If I try to do the same with urllib2, it seems to work:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.canistream.it/services/search?movieName=The%20Wizard%20of%20Oz")
>>> print r.read(100)
[{"actors":"Judy Garland, Frank Morgan, Ray Bolger","year":1939,"description":"","title":"The Wizard
```

Now, I can rewrite the app in urllib2 and that'd solve things, but I prefer working with requests if I can help it, and I'm curious as to why there'd be this discrepancy in response. Anyone have ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Likely, a difference in request headers. I'd suggest to dump both requests and compare them.

Comment: Does it work if you try it like [this code](https://github.com/bulv1ne/CanIStreamIt/blob/master/canistreamit/canistreamit.py]?

Comment: Maybe because we blocked you from trying to scrape our website without asking our permission.  If you don't play nice, you can't have access to our data.

Comment: @AlexandruPetrescu I'm sorry; I was working with [this package](https://github.com/bulv1ne/CanIStreamIt) and it honestly (if naively) hadn't occur to me that it might not be condoned by Urban Pixels. Can you shoot me a note (dylan (at) vox (dot) com) if you get a chance to talk this out? Again, apologies, and I'll refrain from pulling any data until I hear back from you.